# Solution wide build configurations in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project, solution, buildconfiguration

I can chose build options like \MT or \MD in the project settings. But since I have a Visual Studio solution with multiple projects, I am looking for a way to define those options or add additional build configurations on a solution wide level. How this possible in current Visual Studio releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the global settings are in the properties manager in the view menu.

You open that, and pick a project and expand it.   There will be various kinds of property sets.  Open up the set that applies to you, and make your changes there.

Once those are set, tell your normal project properties to inherit from parent, then you should be good to go.

[This link may be useful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/669zx6zc.aspx)

Comment: I know the property manager, but where can I edit solution wide configurations there?

Comment: pick a project and expand it.   You should see a list of property pages that you can modify.  Those are the global ones.

Comment: This link is an image similar to what you should see when you expand it... http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_O1v1NpncBZU/Su4JPlomD4I/AAAAAAAAAC0/SE_Echv5id8/s320/PropertyManager.jpg

Comment: I cannot see a solution wide property there. It only shows completely global ones like `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` or `Core Windows Libraries`. Modifying there would affect other solutions as well, I guess.

Comment: In your screenshot, I see so called general settings for the solution. Why don't I have those in the list? What version of Visual Studio are you using?